# I need to create a second constructor per my requirements, but I'm receiving an error. Do I need to use a different type of constructor?

Tags: c#

```
namespace ShapesDemo
{
    abstract class GeometricFigure
    {
        private int width, height;

        public GeometricFigure(int width, int height)
        {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        public int Width
        {
            get { return width; }
            set 
            {
                width = value;
                ComputeArea();
            }
        }

        public int Height
        {
            get { return height; }
            set
            {
                height = value;
                ComputeArea();
            }
        }

        public abstract int ComputeArea();
    }
 }

 class Rectangle : GeometricFigure
 {
        private int area;

        public Rectangle(int width, int height) : base (width, height)
        {
        }

        public override int ComputeArea()
        {
            area = Width * Height;
            return area;
        }
    }

    class Square : Rectangle
    {
        public Square(int width, int height) : base(width, width)
        {
        }

        public Square(int side) : base (width,height) 
        {
        }

        // Here is the problem. There is a requirement to add a 
        // second constructor that uses one dimension for both width and height, 
        // but I am getting an error on any attempt I use. 
        // Any help would be appreciated. Thank you
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you allow `public Square(int width, int height)`? That's exactly the opposite of what `Square` means.

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: You probably meant `public Square(int side) : base(side, side)`.

Answer (score 4):

This one won't compile:

```
public Square(int side) : base (width,height) 
{
}
```

make it

```
public Square(int side) : base (side, side) 
{
}
```

Furthermore, you may want to limit the visibility of the base class constructor.

```
//public GeometricFigure(int width, int height) ...
protected GeometricFigure(int width, int height) ...
```

And you should not provide the `public Square(int width, int height)` that makes no sense.